# PHP reading fields in database

Tags: php, mysql, database, arrays

I have a script that reads my database table fields. Its not reading the first column which is the id.It reads the other fields and adds them into the array. I have added in the for loop a -1 to get every field but to no success.

```
$host=rtrim($_POST['host']);
$user=rtrim($_POST['user']);
$pass=rtrim($_POST['pass']);
$dbselect=rtrim($_POST['dbselect']);
$table=rtrim($_POST['table']);
$classname=rtrim($_POST['classname']);

$key_values = array();

$link = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
$db_select = mysql_select_db($dbselect);
$query = mysql_query('SHOW COLUMNS FROM '.$table.'');


if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect to MySQL server: ' . mysql_error());
}
$dbname = $dbselect;
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($dbname, $link);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die("Could not set $dbname: " . mysql_error());
}
$res = mysql_query('select * from '.$table.'', $link);
$num_fields = mysql_num_fields($res);
for($i=0;$i<$num_fields;$i++){

$key_values[]=mysql_field_name($res,$i);

}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($key_values);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: I just copied your code and it works fine, showing all col-names as expected!

Comment: I thought that bug didn't seem right. Strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/msqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

```
<?php
$host=rtrim($_POST['host']);
$user=rtrim($_POST['user']);
$pass=rtrim($_POST['pass']);
$dbselect=rtrim($_POST['dbselect']);
$table=rtrim($_POST['table']);
$classname=rtrim($_POST['classname']);

$db = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$dbselect);
if($db->connect_error)
        die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '. mysqli_connect_error());

// NOTE real_escape_string may not work for tables untested
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM " . $db->real_escape_string($table));
if (!$result)
        die "Error: " . $db->error;

while ($row = $result->fetch_object())
{
    echo $row->id;
}
$result->close();
$db->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why it might be doing that, but this should be more reliable:

```
$query = mysql_query('select * from `%s`', mysql_real_escape_string($table), $link);
while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
  print_r(array_keys($result));
}
```

Comment: Hence `array_keys($result)` gives one the column names.

Comment: Guess I should have stuck with the `$key_values` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use php native function [mysql_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) (also you need view this [quastion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php/12822319#12822319) before)
After try this code ($res === '[resources](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php)'):

```
$res = mysql_query('select * from '.$table.'', $link);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $key_values[] = array_keys($row);
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($key_values);
echo "</pre>";
```